# Unable to set UIWebview (with Youtube Videos) correctly in UITableViewCells

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, uiwebview

I am adding a UIWebView to my table cells and then embedding youtube video HTML into them. This issue I have is that the videos are not displaying correctly after I scroll down and up  the table again (when cells are reused). The videos are repeated and jumbled across the wrong cells. My implementation is as follows.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString* PlaceholderCellIdentifier = @"LoadYoutubeVid";
    UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:PlaceholderCellIdentifier];        
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        //Add youtube video to the cell contentview
        UIWebView *youtubeVideo = [[UIWebView alloc]init];
        youtubeVideo.tag = YOUTUBE_WEBVIEW;

        [self.contentView addSubview:youtubeVideo];

        [youtubeVideo release];
     }

     //Set youtube video (if exist)
     //Retrieve youtube webview from cell's contentview
     UIWebView *thisYouTubeVideo = (UIWebView *)[self.contentView viewWithTag:YOUTUBE_WEBVIEW];

     //Only set if the cell is suppose to have a youtube webview
     if (self.answerForCell.youtube_url !=nil) 
     {
         //Set the frame of the youtube webview
         thisYouTubeVideo.frame = CGRectMake(CELL_TEXT_LEFT_MARGIN + CELL_AVATAR_WIDTH + CELL_SPACING, currentYAxisValue, CELL_YOUTUBEVIEW_WIDTH, CELL_YOUTUBEVIEW_HEIGHT);

         //Set the key for the youtube webview dictionary (acts as cache)
         NSString *videokey=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",self.answerForCell.youtube_url];

         //Check if the video key exist in cache
         if([self.youtubeVideoCache objectForKey:videokey]) {

              //Replace the youtube webview with the one in the cache *THINK THIS IS WHERE THE ISSUE IS... BUT NOT SURE WHAT
              thisYouTubeVideo = [self.youtubeVideoCache objectForKey:videokey];

         }
         else //If first time loading cell and webview
         {     
              //Create a new videoHTML to be embedded in the youtube webview
              NSString * videoHTML = [self embedYouTube:self.answerForCell.youtube_url frame:CGRectMake(CELL_TEXT_LEFT_MARGIN + CELL_AVATAR_WIDTH + CELL_SPACING, currentYAxisValue, CELL_YOUTUBEVIEW_WIDTH, CELL_YOUTUBEVIEW_HEIGHT)];

              //Embed the new video HTML to the youtube webview
              [thisYouTubeVideo loadHTMLString:videoHTML baseURL:nil];

              //But I want to create a new webview (different address) before storing it into the dictionary cache
              UIWebView *newYouTubeVideo = [[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(CELL_TEXT_LEFT_MARGIN, currentYAxisValue, CELL_YOUTUBEVIEW_WIDTH, CELL_YOUTUBEVIEW_HEIGHT)];

              //Load the videoHTML to the newly created youtube webview before storing it into cache
              [newYouTubeVideo loadHTMLString:videoHTML baseURL:nil];

              //Store the new webview into cache
              [self.youtubeVideoCache setObject:newYouTubeVideo forKey:videokey]; //Save webview in dictionary

         }
      }
      else
      {
          //If cell does not have a youtube webview, set the frame to zero
          thisYouTubeVideo.frame = CGRectZero;
      }
}
```

Can anyone advise me what went wrong in my implementation?

Comment: you found a solution?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose your code is correct in managing cell view dequeing (e.g. when you assign self.contentView I assume this contentView is a view controller property assigned as outlet to the table cell view identified with "LoadYouTubeVid"). So assuming your code is correct in doing basic table management, it seems the rest is ok.

I had in the past a similar issue and the way I found to fix it was to get rid of cell view queues. In such case I was fetching my cell in this way, where each cell has a different identifier. Of course I need to create the cell programmatically. This works.

```
    NSString *cellId = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"YouTubeCell_%d",indexPath.row];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellId];
    if(!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellId];
        [cell.contentView.subviews makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
        cell.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 242);
        UILabel *titleLbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 29)];
        titleLbl.tag=101;
        titleLbl.backgroundColor=[UIColor lightGrayColor];
        titleLbl.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana" size:18.0];
        titleLbl.textAlignment=UITextAlignmentCenter;
        titleLbl.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];
        titleLbl.shadowColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
        titleLbl.shadowOffset=CGSizeMake(0, -1);
        [cell.contentView addSubview:titleLbl];
        [titleLbl release];
        YouTubeView *ytView = [[YouTubeView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 29, 320, 213)];
        ytView.tag=102;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:ytView];
        [ytView release];
        PostModel *post = [self.notizie postAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        //UILabel *titleLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:101];
        titleLbl.text = post.title;
        NSString *ytURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=%@",[post.video lastPathComponent]];
        //NSString *ytURL = post.video;
        //YouTubeView *ytView = (YouTubeView *)[cell viewWithTag:102];
        [ytView setURL:ytURL];
    }
```

All in all this approach is not so bad. It's true that you have a few extra UITableView cell in memory but consider that most of the memory is taken by the UIWebView that you're caching. In such case you don't need to cache it anymore because it is stored in the table view.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. However, it is difficult for me to do so as I already implemented lots of other things within the cell i.e. multiple labels, uiimageview etc. To change the entire workings of the UITableviewCell is too tedious in this case. Sorry I didn't make my case super clear. But still thanks for your suggesttion :)